# How to get Max Egress Flows to match Configured Max Egress Flows in Solace?

Tags: solace

In the Solace CLI, I type in the following command:

```
solace> show message-spool message-vpn Solace_VPN
```

The result output contains a difference between "actual" versus "configured":

```
Flows
  Max Egress Flows:                     100
  Configured Max Egress Flows:          1000
  Current Egress Flows:                 60
  Max Ingress Flows:                    100
  Configured Max Ingress Flows:         1000
  Current Ingress Flows:                22
```

How do I get "Max Egress Flows" and "Configured Max Egress Flows" to align?

Is it as easy as restarting my Message VPN (but this will disconnect all my existing clients)?

It this just a limitation of the community edition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the output, it would appear that your message-broker is configured to only operate at the default 100 connection scaling tier.

There are two options to get the limits to align:

1. If you [meet the system requirements](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/SW-Broker-Specific-Config/Scaling-Tier-Resources.htm#System) for the 1000 connections scaling tier, you can increase your connection scaling tier to 1000 using the procedure [here](https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/SW-Broker-Specific-Config/Configuring-Conn-Scale-Tiers.htm).
2. Manually lower the VPN limits. This can be easily done by going to "Message VPNs, ACLs & Bridges" tab in SolAdmin, clicking on "Edit Message VPN", and adjusting the limits in the "Advanced Properties" tab.